# Time complexity for Java ArrayList insert operation

Tags: java, arraylist

I know the ArrayList in Java is actually implemented with array. So inserting a element into the array seems expensive, because we need to shift all element whose index larger than the insert position. And the worst case, which is inserting at the begin of the array, might be O(n) in time complexity?

I'm writing a performance sensitive program, and I frequently used insert operation. I'm not sure if this will be a bottleneck, if so I have to find some better data structure to do this.

Comment: Use `LinkedList`

Comment: You never move objects, only references (pointers).  Inserting is O(n) but with a very small constant multiplier.  Depending on where you are inserting (head, tail or middle) you might want a `LinkedList` instead, but we cannot tell you without a lot more detail on your access and mutation patterns.

Comment: Personally, I have no idea how anyone could implement an `ArrayList` data structure without an array. For answer, `LinkedList` indeed is better for inserting, but you have to pay the price for `get(int)` because that has changed from `O(1)` to `O(n)`.

Comment: a) The constant factors are so low that `ArrayList` still, in practice, beats most other data structures for insertions in the middle or beginning of the list.  b) Very few insertions are anywhere but the end of the list, in most applications.

Comment: LinkedList is not a guaranteed improvement gain. For one, you mention inserting in the middle of the list. That means you first have to find the middle of the list, which is O(n) for LinkedLists but O(1) for ArrayList. You have to very carefully program, using a ListIterator, all access to the LinkedList, and not change the list in any other way to avoid ConcurrentModificationExceptions.

Comment: This question can provide you a few hints in which situation which list implementation (there's also more complex ones, like skip list, beside array and single and double linked list), but after all you have to do an [amortized analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amortized_analysis) if you want to write a performance sensitive program (part).

Comment: If you really frequently need to insert somewhere in between you might be better of using `LinkedList`. However in regular applications `ArrayList` beats `LinkedList`, there are only few examples that speak for `LinkedList`. If you are unsure you **will need** to make **experiments** and measure the performance of both versions. If you want more specific answers you will need to provide us some code and representative input data sets, otherwise we can't tell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are some benchmark results (AL for `ArrayList`, LL for `LinkedList`, "edit" means insertion and deletion):

```
Benchmark            (SIZE)  Mode  Samples      Score  Score error  Units

AL_accessFirst        10000  avgt        5      2.945        0.159  ns/op
AL_accessLast         10000  avgt        5      2.964        0.255  ns/op
AL_accessMiddle       10000  avgt        5      2.932        0.114  ns/op
AL_editFirst          10000  avgt        5   1898.086      100.413  ns/op
AL_editLast           10000  avgt        5     20.434        2.096  ns/op
AL_editMiddle         10000  avgt        5    893.348       31.074  ns/op
LL_accessFirst        10000  avgt        5      2.901        0.150  ns/op
LL_accessLast         10000  avgt        5      3.001        0.312  ns/op
LL_accessMiddle       10000  avgt        5   8645.194      358.769  ns/op
LL_editFirst          10000  avgt        5      8.261        0.373  ns/op
LL_editLast           10000  avgt        5     10.703        2.873  ns/op
LL_editMiddleIndx     10000  avgt        5  17075.179      730.738  ns/op
LL_editMiddleIter     10000  avgt        5   8273.984      345.155  ns/op
```

Results are from here: https://stuartmarks.wordpress.com/2015/12/18/some-java-list-benchmarks/